# Configuring JBehave to run multithread TestNG tests

Tags: java, integration-testing, bdd, testng, jbehave

I'm trying to create a Proof-of-Concept of using JBehave and TestNG together. What I want to do, is to run a story simultaneously in multiple threads in order to test my codes thread safety.

I have a simple class that only does one thing, calculates modulo 7 on a given integer value. I've created a simple BDD test for this class. I've set up my BDD test as described in JBehave "[Getting started](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/getting-started.html)" documentation. The only difference is, that in my JUnitStory file, instead of using JUnit's @Test annotation, I've used TestNG's

```
@org.testng.annotations.Test(threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 100, timeOut = 10000)
```

When I run the test, everything goes fine for the first 70-90% of the cases, then an exception occurs and the rest of the runs fail

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 100, Failures: 11, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

The exception that occurs is

```
FAILED: run
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:768)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:656)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:92)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.submit(StoryManager.java:203)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runningStory(StoryManager.java:138)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.filterRunning(StoryManager.java:122)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runningStoriesAsPaths(StoryManager.java:107)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.performStories(StoryManager.java:93)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStories(StoryManager.java:81)
....
```

I'm relatively new to both JBehave and TestNG, so I was wondering if this could be simply a configuration issue or is it actually a bug in JBehave.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the thread pool has been shutdown and you (or JBehave) is trying to submit tasks to it?

Comment: No idea, but the exception would indicate that. That's why I asked if it could simply be a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just need to have 2 or more test classes, and configure your testing.xml file to run all classes in that package as a group.  Because TestNG generally forks threads  "by class" (this is the default configuration??), you need to have multiple classes or else it will run all 10 of your method invocations inline, one at a time.